# `AndEngine` Samples are not running on Eclipse by updating to Latest anddorid SDK and ADT

Tags: java, android, andengine, eclipse-adt

It was working fine but when i updated my `eclipse` to latest `ADT` and `SDK` it gave me this error.

```
12-15 14:58:07.501: E/AndroidRuntime(639): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.andengine.AndEngine
```

If any one faced this before then please help me, because of this my AndEngine projects are also giving me the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this issue by following these steps.

First I created new Library called `AndEngineLibs` and add all AndEngine supporting libraries to it.

Then in the project properties->java build path->Order and Export is checked the `AndEngineLibs`

like shown. I don't know it is related or not but it worked for me :) [image]

Comment: actually in latest sdk we have to use "libs" folder instead of "lib". may b this is the reason of class not found .

Comment: May be you are right but have to test it? But anyhow this trick resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are only three reasons you will ever get this error:

1. The class genuinely doesn't exist. If you are using code from an official example and getting this, make sure you have the latest build of the library
2. You have not added the jar to your build path. To fix this, right click on the jar in Eclipse, and do Build Path ► Add to Build Path.
3. Your jar is not in the `/libs` folder. This happens when you have added the jar to the build path, but newer versions of ADT need it to be in `/libs`. Put it there and re-add it to the build path.

Mostly, such errors occur because newer versions of the ADT require all external jars to be in the `libs` folder.

Comment: I have added all jar to my lib folder but it did not solved the problem but when i did the above solution it worked. But thanks for your time and +1 for this :)

Comment: @AliImran you need to add jar files in `libs` not `lib` folder. Then no need of your above solution.